# Reduce for loops in the code below

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, time-complexity

I am trying to get friends recommendations for a user based on their direct friends and rank them on their frequency(i.e number of times the recommended friend appeared on user's direct friend lists). Below is the working code to solve the problem.

```
public List<String> getFriendsRecommendations(String user)
{
    Recommendations rd = new Recommendations(); 
    List<String> result= new ArrayList<String>();

    List<String> drfriend = rd.getdirectfriends(user); //return list of direct friend for the user.

    List<ArrayList<String>> allfriends = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    Map<String, Integer> mapfriend = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    List<String> userfriend = rd.getfriends(user); //returns the list of all the friends for a given user.

    int counter =0;
    for(String s: drfriend)
    {
        allfriends.add(new ArrayList<String>(rd.getfriends(s)));
        rd.intersection(userfriend, allfriends.get(counter), mapfriend);
        counter++;

    }
    result.addAll(mapfriend.keySet());

   //Sorting based on the value of hashmap. friend with highest value will be recommended first
    Collections.sort(result, new Comparator<String>(){
        public int compare(String s1, String s2)
        {
            if(mapfriend.get(s1) > mapfriend.get(s2))
                return -1;
            else if(mapfriend.get(s1) < mapfriend.get(s2))
                return 1;
            else if(mapfriend.get(s1) == mapfriend.get(s2))
            {
                return s1.compareTo(s2);
            }
            return 0;
        }
    });


    return result;
}

public void intersection(List<String> lt1, ArrayList<String> lt2, Map<String, Integer> ranked)
{
    lt2.removeAll(lt1); // ignoring the friends that user is already connected to

    for(String st: lt2)
    {
        boolean val = ranked.containsKey(st);
        if(val)
        {
            int getval = ranked.get(st);

            ranked.put(st, getval+1); //friend name as a key and the value would be the count.
        }
        else
        {
            ranked.put(st, 1); 
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know if there is more efficient way to solve the above problem instead of using 2 for loops?

Comment: *I would like to know if there is more efficient way to do this?* — to do *what* exactly? Also, your question's title is ambiguous at best.

Comment: Try posting on the Code Review Stack Exchange

Comment: @JonnyHenly I would like to know if there is any way I can reduce the number of for loops in the above code?

Comment: OFFTOPIC but always use the most readable, not the most efficient way and it always pays back with good performance.

Answer (score 1):

Quick tip for your Comparator: Get the two values you are interested in comparing at the start and store them in variables, that way you only do a maximimum of 2 get calls instead of 6 in your current worst case scenario (each get call will hash the String, so less is better).

As for simplifying the for loops, could you just get a list of friends of friends and count the occurrences of each friend in that list? Then afterwards, remove any friends you are already friends with.

Comment: Thanks for the quick tip